# Split a string using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, split

My string is

```
"S001P001Q001"
```

I want to split the string into:

```
['S001', 'P001', 'Q001']
```

I tried this steps:

```
test_re = re.compile("(P?[^P]+)") 
result_str = test_re.findall(str1)
```

Comment: How? In substrings of length 4, or after each block of numbers, or after each 1, or before each letter, or ...

Comment: What have you tried? Anything? This is literally the first lesson in most Python tutorials.

Comment: I would like to split the string before each letter?

Comment: @Ayan why the question mark, are you not sure?

Comment: I tried this steps: test_re = re.compile("(P?[^P]+)")
result_str = test_re.findall(str1)

Comment: here it is `re.findall(r'[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*', string)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Wouldn't `\d` be meaningful, instead of `[^A-Za-z]`?

Comment: but he said `I would like to split the string before each letter?`

Comment: Sorry mistakenly i put '?' mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like i said in my comment, you could use `re.findall` instead of `re.split` method.

```
>>> s = "S001P001Q001"
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*', s)
['S001', 'P001', 'Q001']
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]\d*', s)
['S001', 'P001', 'Q001']
```

`[A-Za-z]` - Matches an alphabet.

`[^A-Za-z]*` -  Matches zero or more non-alphabetic characters.

`\d*` - Matches zero or more digit characters.

So the above `findall` function start matching from an alphabet, matches greedily all the zero or more non-alphabetic characters until an alphabet is identified. Once it finds an alphabet, it stops matching. Now from the second alphabet, it matches all the chars upto the next alphabet. Likewise it goes on.

Comment: I have got solution from your answer. Could you please explain?

Comment: If the string consist the special character, how will i modify the delimeter? i mean, split the string before the special character also.